# After deleting cell contents, cell is no longer "blank" when comparing in a conditional using == ""

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

In my `else` statement below, if a cell in column G is blank I want to clear the contents (the timestamp) of another cell in column F using the event function `onEdit()`. However, after testing the code and deleting values, the cell is no longer recognized as blank when comparing `e.value` to a blank cell using `e.value == ""`.  What can I use in the conditional that determines if a cell is truly blank after having deleted a previous value from the cell?

```
function onEdit(e) 
{
  var ss = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var row = e.range.getRow(); //row the user has edited
  var rowHeader = 1;
  var colStart = 7 //Column that contains Departure outcome values
  var colToUpdate = 6; //Check out timestamp column to update if user edits a cell in Departure column

  if(e.range.rowStart > rowHeader && e.range.columnStart === colStart && (e.value !="" || !0))
  {
    ss.getRange(row,colToUpdate).setValue(new Date()); // place time stamp in Check Out column
  }
  else if(e.range.rowStart > rowHeader && e.range.columnStart === colStart && e.value == "")
  {
    ss.getRange(row,colToUpdate).clearContent();
  }
}
```

[image]

Link to spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11vTNBa-YVjyACKPjWDO97Zs397mJrNHnXPDnpGDoVGQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

The `value` property of the **edit event object** only is included when:

1. A single cell is edited
2. The value of the edited edited cell after it's edited is not blank.

Considering the above `e.value == ""` always will be `false` for blank cells because `e.value` returns `undefined`.